# NativeScript build failed after adding telerik ui plugin

Tags: telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm building a NativeScript app. For implementing Drawer, I'm trying to use 'Telerik NativeScript UI' plugin. But, something is not working after installing the plugin & my NativeScript build is getting failed.

Here are 2 screenshots of the build failed.

[image]

[image]

My package.json file content

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.testapp",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "0.1.1",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.1.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.9.0",
    "babel-types": "6.10.2",
    "babylon": "6.8.1",
    "filewalker": "0.1.2",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

My NativeScript CLI version is 2.0.1

Any idea, what's probably going wrong ?

**-------It's fixed-------**

The solution is, after getting the error..

- Don't remove the plugin
- Remove the platform(android/ios)
- Add the platform once again(android/ios)
- Rebuild the app

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
platform remove android
```

and then

```
platform add android
tns run android
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I did that & recovered my old state. But, what's the issue with the plugin? I want 'Drawer' functionality in my app & I think that's the single plugin which can do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue every time I try to add a new plugin to nativescript (e.g the phone, telerik-UI, and contact plugins). What worked for me was just navigating into **platform > android** and then running `gradlew clean`. This way you wouldn't have to re-add the android platform every time you add a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I never tried that one. Next time , I'll do. But, I'd fixed my problem by - adding platform again rather than removing platform & adding platform. But, even if that seems like Telerik NativeScritp UI has some error in it because of which it's not working with AngularJS2 & TypeScript. Now, waiting for the new release of the plugin.

Comment: Glad to hear that you managed to fix your problem. I have found a lot of plugins for Nativescript to be very hit or miss as to whether they work as intended. I myself am running into issues in other areas related to plugins as well.
Good luck!